# Bar chart with continuous data in x axis

Tags: html, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I want to display the data from the following csv in a bar chart grouping the x axis (Access_grade); like a histogram but instead of the frequency in the y axis, the average Mean of each division (every 0.5 points of access_grade for example, a different bar in x and the y displaying the average Mean obteained of all the points inside that x range):

```
Access_grade,Mean
9.85,2.28
10.64,7.01
10.0,5.63
10.92,5.7
11.69,6.39
11.79,7.08
11.03,6.1
10.47,5.61
10.1,6.56
12.13,7.49
11.94,6.98
10.96,5.8
10.45,5.61
10.45,5.95
12.62,7.38
```

Any help?

Maybe something like this with c3, but as there are many points, the bar is not constructed properly... What can I do?

```
var Grade_access_bar = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#grade_access_bar',
    data: {
        url: 'grades_access.csv',
        x: 'Access_grade',
        types: {
            Grade:'bar'
        },
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            label: {
                text: "Average grade",
                position: "outer-middle"
            },
            min: 1,
            max: 9,
            padding: {top: 46},
            tick: {outer: false}
        },
        x: {
            label: {
                text: "Access grade PAU",
                position: "outer-center"
            },
            min: 9,
            max: 14,
            padding: {right: 0.2,left:0.15},
            tick: {
                outer: false,
                count:1,
                fit:false,
                values: [9,10,11,12,13,14]
            }
        }
    },
    size: {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
        anchor: 'top-right',
        x: 20,
        y: 300
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: @Shashank maybe you could help... Like the comment you gave me about the histogram